# eclipse does not install on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, java

i want to use BIRT reporting tool of eclipse for which i have downloaded the following zip:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-reporting-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip

i do not have eclipse installed in my windoes 7 so i am using this link. now, i downloaded the zip, extracted eclipse folder from it, but when i double click on eclipse- application in that folder to run eclipse, i get the following error:

```
 A jre or jdk must be available in order to run Eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching th efollowing locations:
[Drive]:/...eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH
```

what could be the reason? how do i solve it?

Comment: `A jre or jdk must be available in order to run Eclipse.` install it then.

Comment: Is google really, really *that* hard to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install JDK first and then install Eclipse.
Java is not provided in a Windows machine by default. And it is not installed as part of Eclipse.
*You* have to [download it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install Java in your PC

Comment: ah gotcha, i have always used netbeans where jdk comes along with it, have never used eclipse before. okay so do i need to install the jdk at the same locaiton where i have my eclipse folder?

Comment: No. Just install JDK in the default location `C:\Program Files` etc.After that Eclipse is smart enough to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows environment variable

```
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

will help. Replace `%JAVA_HOME%` with the path to the JDK or create a second variable

```
JAVA_HOME = c:\path\to\jdk
```

If there are multiple paths in PATH you can separate them with ";"